# Procedure to return dates in same month and one month after @date. Inclusive dates in SQL. Test Question failing

Tags: sql, date, procedure

[TESTDOME Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7PIz.png)

I'm having difficulty understanding what I am doing wrong in this scenario, is it something to do with both dates need to be inclusive?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ItemsBought (@date DATE) AS
BEGIN
SELECT DAY(dateBought) as day, MONTH(dateBought) as month, name
FROM items
WHERE MONTH(dateBought) 
BETWEEN MONTH(@date)
AND DATEADD(month, 1, convert(varchar(25), @date, 101));
END;
```

I have attempted to return dates from specific months yet getting a failed error message : 'some items are bought in a time period greater than a month'

I've tried using the <= and >= but no avail.

Comment: Firstly, only tag a single rdbms, mysql is not SQL server. Second, provide sample data and desired results so we know what you trying to accomplish. Third, please don't use images except for UI related questions.

Comment: I believe you misunderstood the task. I think `dateBought` should be between `@date` and `DATEADD(month, 1,@date)`, or at least I read the task that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE itemsBought
@date DATE
AS
BEGIN
SELECT DAY(dateBought) AS dayBought,
       MONTH(dateBought) AS monthBought,
       name
FROM items
WHERE dateBought >= @date AND dateBought <= DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @date)
ORDER BY dateBought
END
```

If you want to use between then try this

```
SELECT DAY(dateBought) as day, MONTH(dateBought) as month, name
FROM items
WHERE dateBought BETWEEN @date AND DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @date)
```

Comment: Thankyou! This has resolved the problem! I understand what I was doing wrong now